# How do I prove that $\lim_\sigma \int_{-\sigma}^{\sigma}\frac{\sin(\sigma x)}{\pi x}\,dx =1$?

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

I am not sure how to evaluate the following integral. It gives $1$ if I am not wrong as I read it in a book, but the method is not shown. How do I prove the following
$$\lim_{\sigma \to \infty} \int_{-\sigma}^{\sigma}\frac{\sin(\sigma x)}{\pi x}\,dx =1$$

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) for more details.

Comment: Perhaps the question intended to say $$\lim_{\sigma \to \infty} \int_{-\sigma}^{\sigma} \frac{\sin(\sigma x)}{\pi x}\,dx = 1$$ ?

Comment: @AntonioVargas yes sorry for not mentioning.

Comment: I received a close flag for question being unclear I don;t understand whats unclear in my question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not true. For any $\sigma\in\mathbb{R}^+$ we have:
$$ \int_{-\sigma}^{\sigma}\frac{\sin(\sigma x)}{\pi x} = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\sigma^2}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx = \frac{2}{\pi}\cdot\operatorname{Si}(\sigma^2)$$
where $\operatorname{Si}$ stands for the [sine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html) function. The RHS is close to one for every $\sigma$ (especially if $\sigma$ is big), equals one in an infinite number of points and its limit as $\sigma\to +\infty$ is one, but, for instance,
$$\frac{2}{\pi}\cdot\operatorname{Si}(1) = 0.602295\ldots $$